# Is this sentence correct? I got my driving licence so I can go to work also by car

Tags: writing, email

I want to send an email to the place where I work
Hi....,
I hope you are doing well. Just a quick email to let you know that I got my driving license so I can go to work also by car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "So I can **also** go to work by car"! Using *also* right after the verb is more frequently used than placing it before the object.